# Sign-in with Google without Google Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library for web

Tags: google-signin

I want to add "Sign-in with Google" as an alternative to creating an account when signing up for our services.

I want the process to retrieve the user's email address and name. That's it.

And this example was all I needed

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web

Worked great. Very similar to Log in with Facebook, which I added last week.

But now I read that it won't be supported after March 2023.

Using the destined-for-the-dustbin JS code, I can get back useful info about the account I'm logging in with.

ID: 10855600*******690837;Frank;Hart;frank.hart*****@gmail.com

The parameter passed to the callback function has a getBasicProfile() method which does the job

var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

But using the new code, I found (by trial and error) that the parameter passed to the callback function is an object, which has three fields, the only potentially useful one called credential, with content such as:

eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjQ2Mjk0OTE3NGYxZWVkZjRmOWY5NDM0ODc3YmU0ODNiMzI0MTQwZjUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJuYmYiOjE2Mjg4NTQzOTcsImF1ZCI6IjY1MjE0Nzk1NjY0My05aWVmdHN2bmZraDVma2x1NHUxOGg1Ymc3MDA0YjdsOC5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsInN1YiI6IjEwODU1NjAwNDY3OTg0NzY5MDgzNyIsImVtYWlsIjoiZnJhbmsuaGFydDA0N0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXpwIjoiNjUyMTQ3OTU2NjQzLTlpZWZ0c3ZuZmtoNWZrbHU0dTE4aDViZzcwMDRiN2w4LmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwibmFtZSI6IkZyYW5rIEhhcnQiLCJwaWN0dXJlIjoiaHR0

Now, my guess is that I have to send that string to my server, and do something with it, possibly involving the "Client secret" that is associated with the App on developers.google.com. But I've been looking most of the day, and I'm not sure if what I've found is necessary - I hope it isn't

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Do I now need to become an OAuth2 programmer just to add a Sign-in with Google button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that you do not need to learn OAuth2, you do not need to follow the backend-auth guide linked in your question.  This migration actually *removes* the complexity OAuth2, access and refresh tokens from sign-in. Yes, there is the difficulty of learning and understanding the new and different way of securely sharing the user profile. Hopefully, after cresting over the learning curve you'll see how this makes working with a profile more simple.

JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) are now used to securely share the Google Account profile.

That big pile of text--the credential, it is a base-64 encoded and a JWT.
[jwt.io](https://jwt.io) has an online JWT decoder that's handy for testing and a nice writeup of working with JWTs.  After decode its just a JSON object, no get methods are necessary, just access the individual fields.

All this said, you need to decide whether decode should take place in the user's browser, or on your backend server. This depends upon how you're working with the profile and your setup. Typically, you'd decode on your server after a redirect using [data-login_uri](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-attributes) in HTML or [login_uri](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#login_uri) in JS.

There are a large number of JWT decode libraries available, so it's very likely you'll be able to add a JWT library, decode it and you're all set to access the individual fields in the credential.

Comment: you just made my weekend, friend!

Comment: once the user signs in, I decode the credential on the backend, how does the backend know that the user signed in and can access restricted endpoints? Do I need to generate my own access and refresh token? Thanks!